# When tlp is enabled ubuntu desktop won't load after installing nvidia-drivers only when on battery

Tags: drivers, nvidia, battery, tlp

So I just installed nvidia-drivers on my laptop, and when connected to AC power it boots fine. But when I try to switch it on on battery, I get a black screen after booting instead of the ubuntu desktop. I can open the tty2 terminal, so I guess something is preventing the nvidia driver from working properly. When I disable tlp it works fine though. So I presume tlp is somehow preventing the driver from loading properly on boot when on battery. It would be really helpful if someone could tell me if there's a way to change the tlp configuration to fix it.

(I'm on ubuntu 20.04, tlp 1.3.1, nvidia-driver-510, secure boot disabled)